# how to transfer variables in java

Tags: java

I am still fairly new to coding in java and I am trying to build a text game to help me learn. I am having issues transferring a variable to help me test out specs.

```
   String a = user.next();

     if(a.equals("warrior")){
           System.out.println("You start to feel stronger, feels like you could run through a brick wall and keep on going without a scrath on you.\n" + 
              "Of course you might want to wait on that for awhile.\n" +
              "********************************************************\n*\t\tAchievement got: Dumb as a rock!\t\t\t\t\t\t *\n********************************************************");
           String specW = ("warrior");
           comW (warrior);
     }

    public static void comW (warrior){
     System.out.println("Testing1");
    }
```

is anyone able to help me figure out why I keep having errors?

Comment: `public static void comW (warrior){` You need to give a type to `warrior`

Comment: what litelite means is that you should add the type String to the method's signature: `public static void comW (String warrior)`

Comment: You seems to need to read some tutos, there is lots of mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
 comW (specW);
 }

public static void comW (String warrior){
 System.out.println(warrior);
}
```

Do above changes in your code.
Basically you are passing a variable in comW method but the variable is not declared. 
Secondly, in your comW method you didn't give parameter type.

I would recommend you to follow some tutorials carefully before posting question here.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a string variable with name **specW** but passing a variable **warrior** to **comW** function. So change the function parameter to **specW**.  Also in the definition of function **comW** the parameter **warrior** is not given any type so give it a String type.

```
String a = user.next();

 if(a.equals("warrior")){
       System.out.println("You start to feel stronger, feels like you could run through a brick wall and keep on going without a scrath on you.\n" + 
          "Of course you might want to wait on that for awhile.\n" +
          "********************************************************\n*\t\tAchievement got: Dumb as a rock!\t\t\t\t\t\t *\n********************************************************");
       String specW = ("warrior");
       comW (specW); // 1st Change
 }

public static void comW (String warrior){ // 2nd Change
 System.out.println("Testing1");
}
```